# Cancel Leave Event when closing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, events

I have got a textbox on a form with a method being called from the txPredio_Leave event.

My problem is that is the user has focus on the textbox and then close the form by clicking the little X close icon in the top corner or by calling  `this.ActiveMdiChild.Close();` or by calling

```
    private void mnucerrarTodas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Form form in this.MdiChildren)
        {
            form.Close();
        }
    }
```

The txPredio leave execute the method..  then i need doesn't excute this method when the form is closing.

i have think that one solution could be ask in leave event if form is closing

```
        private void txPredio_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            if(!form is closing)//pseudo code
               Check_Load_Predio();
        }
```

or other solution could be

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {   
       //code for cancel the txPredio_Leave event
    }
```

Solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339362/how-to-stop-textbox-leave-event-firing-on-form-close) Doesn´t work for me. Then I need one solution for my problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the `Leave` handler in `FormClosing`.

**EDIT**: Like this:

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{   
    txPredio.Leave -= txPredio_Leave;
}
```

Comment: I am searching for the best answer to this issue and I found SLaks code the best!  Thanks a lot SLaks!